ASP.NET Core 6 Web API : autogenerate server certificate (same name as projectname)
I have an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API project running with kestrel, which hosts an OPC UA client library (OPCLabs easyopc, based on OPCFoundation OPC UA client library). This client library is wrapped in a nuget package, and generates its own client certificate.
My issue is that when I start the Web API project, the hosted OPC UA client manages to create its own certificate (in the folder OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications\certs), and connects to the correct server.
After some time (days), I discover another certificate in this folder, called webapi, same name as the Web API project...
I struggle to find out why this certificate is created, and why this is placed there in that folder.
I don't use redirection to HTTPS in my Web API (app.UseHttpsRedirection()), and the clients are connecting to the Web API through localhost and http.
My question is, what triggers the generation of the webapi certificate? Could this be the underlying OPCFoundation library?
Is is possible to automatically create a webapi certificate if this is not specified?
I have disabled app.UseHttpsRedirection().

Normally, it will not generate the certificate if you don't have the codes to generate in template web api project. According to your description, it seems the OPC UA client library helps you generate it.

Hello. Since you are using QuickOPC , why don't you just post this on our Tech Support - https://www.opclabs.com/forum/index ? (I am from from OPC Labs). Diagnosing it may require multiple "roundtrips" and is thus not quite suitable for SO. For start, what is the full file name of the first certificate created, and what is the full file name of the one with "webapi"?

@ZbynekZ I have a current ongoing support case with OPC Labs, and to my understanding, everything points to the OPCLabs OPC Client library (via OPCFoundation perhaps), is responsible for creating these certificatres. The intention with this SO post was to make sure that asp.net is not creating these, to rule out why this is happening.

ASP.NET by itself is not touching OPC Foundation\CertificateStores at all.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
